# Connect to Weaviate Database results in Key Error

Tags: weaviate

I'm trying to set up weaviate locally. Already cost me several hours as I'm getting errors for every step I do. Nothing works as described. I use ubuntu 22.04 and docker and latest online manuals. I figured out one way that works how I can connect to my local weaviate docker:

```
import weaviate.classes as wvc
import os
import requests
import json

client = weaviate.connect_to_local( 

)
```

Now as soon as I add the OpenAI Key "headers=...":

```
import weaviate
import weaviate.classes as wvc
import os
import requests
import json

client = weaviate.connect_to_local( 
headers={"X-OpenAI-Api-Key": os.environ["sk-..."]}
)
```

I get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/johannes/test4.py", line 8, in <module>
    headers={"X-OpenAI-Api-Key": os.environ["sk-..."]}
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/os.py", line 680, in __getitem__
    raise KeyError(key) from None
KeyError: 'sk-...'
```

I use Python 3.10.12, I tried other Python versions but get a new error for each version I try. Any ideas what I can do to get this running or what I'm doing wrong? It's really that none of the code works for me, even not the older python interface v3, just giving errors.

Comment: At a first glance, it seems that `os.environ["sk-..."]` returns a `None` value. Did you try setting the OpenAI key as a string?

Comment: Like this: `headers={"X-OpenAI-Api-Key": "sk-..." }`

Comment: wow great, that did the job :-)!! If you provide it as answer I can accept it. Thanks so much for your help, it really means a lot. The manual of them just has error over error everywhere, nothing is working. It's so frustrating and costs so much time @BobvanLuijt

Comment: sure, happy to help! I know some people at Weaviate so I’ll make sure to let them know. One question, do you have one or two links where this can be seen?

Comment: This is wrong on a lot of places. With the current manual it is neither possible to get the v3 of their python interface to work with a local installation, nor the v4. I tried everything possible and different explanation pages of them like the quickstart, the python manual... nothing works, everywhere you get a different error. I think someone of them should do what they actually describe before publishing. Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue lies with:

`os.environ["sk-..."]}`

This basically says: “show me the value for environment variable “sk-…”. Or in other words; it looks for the API-key as an environment variable instead of something like: `OPENAI-KEY`. That’s the reason why it gets a `None` value.

So, this can be easily resolved:

This `os.environ["sk-..."]}` should be: `"sk-..."`

Example:

```
client = weaviate.connect_to_local( 
    headers={"X-OpenAI-Api-Key": "sk-..."}
)
```

**UPDATE:**

The confusion seems to be that `os.environ["X-OpenAI-API"]` does not mean that you should replace `X-OpenAI-API` with your actual key (e.g., `sk-...` but that you set an environment variable like `$ export X-OpenAI-API=sk-...` this is simply a security measurement.

Comment: Just note that the error was copy and paste from the weaviate manual. It is not from me. They even managed to implement different errors on different code parts for the same aboves line of code. One time they forget the "Key" and just say "X-OpenAI-API". The other time they use sth. else instead of os.environ... which also does not work. The version that works as you describe above unfortunatley is never included in their code today (hopefully in the future for others). It is costing me hours of time and really frustrating.

Comment: Note the update in the answer, I think I understand where the confusion comes from

Comment: Yes, unfortunately it makes totally no sense to replace code with an API key. No one would get this idea, it just does not make sense. Just wonder why they do not write a manual that is understandable.